# Which scripture talks about avatara of Srimad VallabhAcharya?

Tags: avatars, vaishnavism, pushti-marga

It is believed that the propagator of shuddha advaita pushti marga, Sri Vallabha was born as a fruit of 100 somayAgas done by his ancestors.

Is there any scripture or biography which supports him being an avatar of Sri Krishna ?

Comment: I don't think he was Krishna

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury i also think many things about many people but thats another topic..

Comment: Yes, in Vallabhacharya's biography, it is written that he was avatara of Lord Krishna.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vallabhacharya followers believe Him to be incarnation of Lord Krishna.

From [second chapter of the book "Shri Vallabhacharya- A divine Jagad Guru"](http://sg.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/87133/6/06_chapter%202.pdf)
 ,

> Shri Vallabh was born in the year 1478 A.D. (Vikrami Samvat 1535) in
>   Champaranya near Raipur in Central India. He was the son Of Shri Laxman Bhatt andIllama garu. Shri Vallabhacharya‘s parents were Brahmin, natives of the Andhra, Region of Southern India. Shri Laxman Bhattji was the descandent of Yagnanarayan Bhatt, to whom **the Lord had promised on the completion of a 100 Somayagnas that the Lord himself would be born in his family.** (page 46-47)

Comment: And vedantins thought that people should not get attracted towards vedic rituals ...